# A direct transcription method for a discrete multi-body plant?

Tags: drake

Drake can't run a multibody plant on continuous mode, because there is one "limit" setting in one joint in sdf file. Unfortunately, Direct Collocation is not suitable for this discrete case, too. Then I find Direct Transcription is not limited in continuous mode. I try to test Direct Transcription with CartPole case.  I got a trouble to setup input port: 
File "cartpol_direct.py", line 27, in 
    input_port_index=plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index())

I want to ask two questions. 
(1) Are Direct Transcription okay for a discrete system, up to four actuations, multi-body system? 
(2) How to setup input port for below CartPole ?

Direct Collocation

Multibody Plant --> OK , Continuous System -- > OK  ,  Discrete System --> X , Multi actuation --> ?

Direct Transcription

Multibody Plant --> ? , Continuous System --> OK,  Discrete System --> OK, Multi actuation --> ?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pydrake.all import (DiagramBuilder, DirectTranscription, MultibodyPlant,
                         MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose, Parser,
                         PiecewisePolynomial, PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer,
                         SceneGraph, Simulator, Solve, TrajectorySource)
from pydrake.systems.framework import InputPortSelection
from underactuated import FindResource

plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.005)
scene_graph = SceneGraph()
plant.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)
file_name = FindResource("models/cartpole.urdf")
Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
plant.Finalize()

context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()

dircol = DirectTranscription(
plant,
context,
num_time_samples=21,
minimum_timestep=0.1,
maximum_timestep=0.4,
input_port_index=plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index())


dircol.AddEqualTimeIntervalsConstraints()

initial_state = (0., 0., 0., 0.)
dircol.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(initial_state, initial_state,
                                dircol.initial_state())
# More elegant version is blocked by drake #8315:
# dircol.AddLinearConstraint(dircol.initial_state() == initial_state)

final_state = (0., math.pi, 0., 0.)
dircol.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(final_state, final_state, dircol.final_state())
# dircol.AddLinearConstraint(dircol.final_state() == final_state)

R = 10  # Cost on input "effort".
u = dircol.input()
dircol.AddRunningCost(R * u[0]**2)

# Add a final cost equal to the total duration.
dircol.AddFinalCost(dircol.time())

initial_x_trajectory = PiecewisePolynomial.FirstOrderHold(
    [0., 4.], np.column_stack((initial_state, final_state)))  # yapf: disable
dircol.SetInitialTrajectory(PiecewisePolynomial(), initial_x_trajectory)

result = Solve(dircol)
assert result.is_success()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)


# Animate the results.
# TODO(russt): Add some helper methods to make this workflow cleaner.
def animate(plant, x_trajectory):
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    source = builder.AddSystem(TrajectorySource(x_trajectory))
    builder.AddSystem(scene_graph)
    pos_to_pose = builder.AddSystem(
        MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose(plant, input_multibody_state=True))
    builder.Connect(source.get_output_port(0), pos_to_pose.get_input_port())
    builder.Connect(pos_to_pose.get_output_port(),
                    scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant.get_source_id()))

    visualizer = builder.AddSystem(
        PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer(scene_graph,
                                   xlim=[-2, 2],
                                   ylim=[-1.25, 2],
                                   ax=ax[0]))
    builder.Connect(scene_graph.get_pose_bundle_output_port(),
                    visualizer.get_input_port(0))

    simulator = Simulator(builder.Build())
    simulator.AdvanceTo(x_trajectory.end_time())


u_trajectory = dircol.ReconstructInputTrajectory(result)
times = np.linspace(u_trajectory.start_time(), u_trajectory.end_time(), 100)
u_lookup = np.vectorize(u_trajectory.value)
u_values = u_lookup(times)

ax[1].plot(times, u_values)
ax[1].set_xlabel("time (seconds)")
ax[1].set_ylabel("force (Newtons)")

x_trajectory = dircol.ReconstructStateTrajectory(result)
animate(plant, x_trajectory)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Collocation is an idea about gradients of a continuous trajectory.  It is only a relevant idea for continuous-time systems.

Direct transcription is well-defined for both discrete- and continuous- time.  I will test your code example shortly.